# Accessing variables from another folder for Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var sourceFile = require('../public/assmt.js');
var mailnamenode=sourceFile.mailname;

var transporter=nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://user@gmail.com:pass@smtp.gmail.com');
exports.sendMail=functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=>{
    var mailOptions={
        to: 'badhushaphysics@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Test Mail',
        html: 'Testing with Node.js'
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,response){
        if(err)
        {
            res.send('Mail not sent');
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.send('Mail sent to'+mailnamenode+'');
        }
    });
});
```

[image: Folders]
Here I want to access a variable from the **assmt.js** and use it in the **index.js** which has the firebase cloud functions.

My **assmt.js** has the code for variable storage.

```js
module.exports.mailname="username@gmail.com";
```

But I get errors at the command prompt. 
**Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '../public/assmt.js'**

Comment: You have to go another step up in the require, use `require ('../../public/subject.js')`

Comment: @AshishJhanwar I tried it too but even though it says same error.

Comment: I am having the same error. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Your question talks about `index.js` and `assmt.js` but the error message refers to `subject.js`.  Where does the `subject.js` file live and which module requires it?  What does that `require` expression say?